# Symfony @ROUTE("/{id}") regex requirements not working

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes, annotations

On a Symfony Controller I am using annotations to match only URIs ending like

```
.../integer-integer
or
.../integer
```

my code

```
 /**
 * @Route("/notification/old/{id}", requirements={"id" = "(^\d+$)|(^\d+\-\d+$)"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
```

According to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#pcre) my pattern is correct.
However, Symfony returns

> No route found for "GET /notification/old/1-1"
> No route found for "GET /notification/old/1"

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably, it will not help, but just note you can write the regex as `^\d+(?:-\d+)?$`.

Comment: lol that works.
 In my understanding Or operator doesn't work in symfony.
because `^\d+$` and `^\d+\-\d+$` on their owns do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression should be causing the issue. You can get rid of alternation, capturing groups, and simplify it to

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

It matches 1 or more digits from the start of a string and then optionally matches a hyphen and 1 or more digits up to the end of string.